# P2p NFC communication between Android and Adafruit PN532

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p

I am looking for a way to establish p2p communication between an Android phone (lets call it **A**) and a PN532+microcontroller (lets call them **B**).

By p2p I mean a scenario in which:

**1.** A sends some application specific data to B

**2.** B receives data and sends a response containing application specific data to A.

I have seen similar questions but most of them date back to 2011, stating that such functionality is not yet supported by the API. Looking at the latest API I can still only see a solution in which **B** is treated as a TAG.

Am I missing something or is the kind of communication I am looking for is still not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to specifically use NFC peer-to-peer mode, then the same answers are valid today: Android only supports Android Beam for P2P communication. Hence, you can, in general, only transmit one message into one direction and you need to tap the Beam UI each time you want to send data. However, if your interaction is exactly 1 message from Android to PN532 and then 1 message from PN532 to Android, and you are okay with tapping the Beam UI when sending from Android, you could use some tricks to first receive the message from Android, then disconnect and reconnect to send the response to Android.

When you are open to support other modes, then you have some options:

1. If the Android device has Android 4.4 or later and supports host card emulation (HCE): Use the PN532 in reader/writer mode and implement a HCE service on the Android side.
2. Otherwise, use the PN532 in host card emulation mode and access it from the Android side using the standard NFC reader/writer API (e.g. IsoDep / NfcA or NfcF).

Comment: Thanks @Michael Roland! I will try to hack my way around this. P.S. I think you can actually avoid having to tap the screen in the latest API version by calling invokeBeam(). This isn't too much of a concern for me though,

Comment: A message from Android and a response back should be possible using just Beam (SNEP). I used it while ago to realize a scavenger hunt using NXP TagWriter on Android and nfcpy's beam script. The TagWriter App could be configured to send a previously found NDEF message to nfcpy beam and received back a message with the next target to find. The leftover in nfcpy's examples/beam.py is the "recv send" action documented at http://nfcpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/beam.html#recv-send.

Comment: @StephenTiedemann I tried this quite a while ago and had the impression that Android quickly times out and that you only have a very short time (my impression was actually *not enough time*) on the PN532 side to process the received message and to generate the response. But I have to admit that I did not further investigate this and what I experienced could have had some completely different source too.

Comment: @MichaelRoland What "beam.py recv send" does is to receive the message as SNEP server and send the response as SNEP client. I've never experienced any timing issue between the two interactions. Obviously the Android side has to do similarly send as client and being able to receive as server, the TagWriter app was doing the trick at the time (though I could not find the configuration options on a current install of TagWriter, maybe it's gone since the UI got updated).